# How can i draw a shape on a graphView using onTouchEvent or any other way?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-graphview, android-touch-event

I am making an app where I have a graphView where the cartesian  X-axis varies from -150 to 150 and Y-axis values vary from 0-150 as shown below.Now I want to draw any shapes over this graphView using the touch of my finger.I want that I should draw any shape over this graph.The coordinates of the drawn shape should be in accordance with X and Y axis values not that of the pixel screen coordinates(which we get using MotionEvent()).

[image: My app screen]

I have tried to achieve this using onTouchEvent() but there the MotionEvent() returns me the pixel coordinates of the screen which all are positive.
The second approach I used is filling all the possible datapoint of the graphView using for loops as show  in code below.I have used setOnDataPointTapListener where I get the DataPoints touched when I tab over the graphView.But the problem here is when i move my finger over the screen for drawing the setOnDataPointTapListener() is not triggered.
Is there any way to do this?I will be very grateful for your help.Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GraphView graph;
    ArrayList<Point> dataPoints;
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dataPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        graph = findViewById(R.id.graphView);
        Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
        graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);
        graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
        viewport.setMaxX(150);
        viewport.setMinX(-150);
        viewport.setMaxY(150);
        viewport.setMinY(0);

        series = new LineGraphSeries<>();
        for (int x = -150; x <= 150; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= 150; y++) {
                DataPoint dataPoint = new DataPoint(x, y);
                //100000 is the max datapoints
                series.appendData(dataPoint, false, 100000);
            }
        }
        graph.addSeries(series);

        series.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Datapoints are " + dataPoint.getX();
                        + " " + dataPoint.getY(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                DataPoint dataPoint1 = (DataPoint) dataPoint;
                int x = (int) dataPoint1.getX();
                int y = (int) dataPoint1.getY();

                dataPoints.add(new Point(x, y));
                Log.d(TAG, "onTap: " + dataPoints.size());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using Cartesian Plotter.

https://github.com/ederdoski/SimpleCartesianPlotter?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7223

You can also add thread in your onTouch() method. Below code worked for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

   Thread CoordinatesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getX();

            Log.e("coordinates", x + ":" + y);

            try {// take a gap for 5000 milisec before displaying new coordinates
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    });
    CoordinatesThread.start();

    return true;
}
```